# coffeescript + jshint = Unused variable: _this

Tags: coffeescript, jshint

Compiling any code with `bare = false` and linting it with `JShint`
results in `Unused variable: _this`.

Solutions to this?
`bare = true` should remain,
besides I'm pretty happy to have `jshint` checking for unused variables. I just want an exception here.

---

By the way, I also get the

```
Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function.
}).call(this);
```

Comment: Why do you refer to both bare and Bare?

Comment: Typo in the question. `--bare`

Answer (score 1):

Why are you running stuff you have written in Coffeescript through jshint? Isn't jshint supposed to be used with handwritten javascript?

If you really want to use a lint tool why don't you use http://www.coffeelint.org/

Lastly this is very similar to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12684758/1269969) here, which was closed as not being a real question.

Comment: Does it matter how was your code produced? Errors could had been presented in the original file as well. Coffeescript during compilation doesn't know about unused variables, undefined variables, camel_case style enforcement and tons of other options your code should conform to.

Comment: Coffeelint specifically ain't aware of used / unused variables and has like 1/3 of the jshint options provided. Including use of undefined variables and modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to run the generated JS through JSHint, you can pass [options](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/) to ignore this warnings like so:

```
###jshint node: true, unused: false ###
```

which compiles to

```
/*jshint node: true, unused: false */
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following [`.jshintrc` settings](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/) in my browser-facing Coffeescript projects

```
// be sure to turn off 'devel' before shipping.
{
  "devel": true,
  "bitwise": true,
  "boss": true,
  "browser": true,
  "camelcase": true,
  "curly": true,
  "eqeqeq": true,
  "eqnull": true,
  "es3": false,
  "esnext": true,
  "forin": false,
  "freeze": true,
  "immed": true,
  "indent": 2,
  "jquery": true,
  "latedef": true,
  "newcap": true,
  "noarg": true,
  "noempty": true,
  "nonbsp": true,
  "nonew": true,
  "plusplus": false,
  "quotmark": "double",
  "strict": false,
  "trailing": true,
  "undef": true,
  "unused": false,
  "predef": ["jQuery", "console"]
}
```